# how to reset one of data in pinia state?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have a design in setting page,every one of them hava reset button, now i using pinia to be store library.
I kown `$reset` is reset the whole pinia state,so,how to reset one of data in pinia state?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typical way I do this:

```
const defaultState = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

export const useFoo = defineStore('foo', {
  state: () => ({ ...defaultState }),
  actions: {
    reset() {
      Object.assign(this, defaultState);
    }
  }
})
```

You get the initial state and a `reset()` action which resets whatever state has to the initial. Obviously, you can pick and choose what you put in `defaultState`.

---

If you only want to reset one particular state prop, without touching anything else, just assign the default value to it:

```
useFoo().foo = 'bar';
```

---

If you find it useful, you can also have a generic `update`, where you can assign multiple values to state in one call:

```
actions: {
  update(payload) {
    Object.assign(this, payload)
  }
}
```

Use it like:

```
useFoo().update({ 
  foo: 'bar',
  // add more props if needed...
});
```

---

Last, but not least, `lodash`'s `pick` can be used to pick and choose what gets reset, from the `defaultState` values, without having to specify the actual values:

```
import { pick } from 'lodash-es';

const defaultState = {
  foo: 'bar',
  boo: 'far'
};

export const useFoo = defineStore('foo', {
  state: () => ({ ...defaultState }),
  actions: {
    reset(keys) {
      Object.assign(this, keys?.length
        ? pick(defaultState, keys)
        : defaultState // if no keys provided, reset all
      );
    }
  }
})
```

use it like:

```
useFoo().reset(['foo']);
```

This only resets `foo` to `'bar'`, but doesn't touch current value of `boo`.

To reset both (using the action above):

```
useFoo().reset(['foo', 'boo']);
```

...or `useFoo().reset()` or `useFoo().reset([])`, both of which reset all the state, because the `keys?.length` condition is falsey.

Here's a working example:

```js
const { createPinia, defineStore, storeToRefs } = Pinia;
const { createApp, reactive, toRefs } = Vue;
const defaultState = {
  foo: "bar",
  boo: "far",
};

const useStore = defineStore("foobar", {
  state: () => ({ ...defaultState }),
  actions: {
    reset(keys) {
      Object.assign(
        this,
        keys?.length ? _.pick(defaultState, keys) : defaultState
      );
    },
  },
});

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const localState = reactive({
      resetFoo: false,
      resetBoo: false,
    });
    const resetStore = () => store.reset(
      [
        localState.resetFoo ? "foo" : null,
        localState.resetBoo ? "boo" : null,
      ].filter((o) => o)
    );
    return { ...storeToRefs(store), ...toRefs(localState), resetStore };
  },
});
app.use(pinia);
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-demi"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pinia/2.0.28/pinia.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="foo" />
  <input v-model="boo" />
  <pre v-text="JSON.stringify({foo, boo}, null, 2)"></pre>
  <hr>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="resetFoo" />ResetFoo</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="resetBoo" />ResetBoo</label>
  <button @click="resetStore">Reset</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: -1?:  changing the state of 'foo' is actually changing the  `defaultState`, so .assign will be a noop. It should be: `const get_default_auth = ()=> {return {default stuff'..}`. This assigns a new object to state

Comment: You're correct, @droid. `defaultState` needs spreading when being assigned to `state`. I've added a working example to the answer.

Comment: Generally the overall strategy works for me, however the spread operator (shallow clone) doesn't seem to break reactivity! defaultState is getting manipulated when using the app. So instead of `...defaultState` I have had to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultState()))` (deep clone) which seems to keep defaultState untouched.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"doesn't seem to break reactivity"*. Where in any of the examples above is `defaultState` reactive? I can't imagine a scenario where you'd want it reactive.

Comment: IMHO, the spread-operator (shallow clone) hasn't worked for me in this context as the original default object seems to get manipulated. Instead, using deep clone manages to do a clean copy of the default object.

Answer (score 4):

Above example doesn't reset one property to the default value when the property is already changed.
That's because the defaultState is reactive, you need to copy the defaultState so it's not reactive anymore.

```
import _pick from 'lodash.pick';

const defaultState = {
  foo: 'bar',
};

export const useStore = defineStore('store', {
  state: () => ({...defaultState}),
  actions: {
    reset(keys) {
      Object.assign(this, keys?.length
        ? _pick(defaultState, keys)
        : defaultState // if no keys provided, reset all
      );
    }
  }
})
```

Use it like this

```
useStore().reset(['foo']);
```

This will now reset `foo` back to `bar`